# STDERR of pg_dump in UTF-8

Tags: unicode, command-line, utf-8, stderr, pg-dump

I am redirecting the stderr of pg_dump to file:

```
pg_dump ...... 2>pg_dump.log
```

but this file is ANSI-encoded. I would like to see it in UTF-8 or Unicode. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

[man pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgdump.html)

```
-E encoding
--encoding=encoding
Create the dump in the specified character set encoding. By default, the dump is created in the database encoding.
```

BTW: regarding "UTF-8 or Unicode", the "or" does not make sense; UTF-8 is one of the encodings of Unicode (other is UTF-16)

Updated: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem. Are you interested in text error messages generated by Postresql or texts from some queries/data from your own data? If the former, I think the LC_MESSAGES setting should work http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/locale.html
Elsewhere, you can always use [iconv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv)

Comment: `Create the DUMP in the specified character set encoding.` I am not talking about dump. I am talking about STDERR messages, which encoding is different.